# Is there a way to tell if a PHP file is being accessed as a script or css file, like you can tell if it is AJAX?

Tags: php

I can determine whether a PHP file is being called via AJAX using this:

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

I would like to know if I can do a similar thing to determine if a PHP file is being called from a web page or if it is being loaded directly in the browser, so if I have some HTML which includes something like this:

```
<script src="jsgenerator.php/functions.js"></script>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssgenerator.php/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

Is there a way for the php files (`jsgenerator.php` or `cssgenerator.php`) to know that they have been loaded in this way? Of course I could look at the final part of the path and see that it's expecting CSS or JS, but I am interested in running code that is conditional upon it being loaded directly in the browser vs loaded from a page (e.g. if you loaded https://example.com/jsgenerator.php/functions.js in your browser, the code would run, but if it was accessed from a `<script src=...` in another page it would not)

Comment: You can check the referrer, which will be the page that included the file or blank if the URL was typed completely into the URL bar.

Comment: in your example your `isset` is redundant. If it's not set, the strtolower will never equal the text string.

Comment: could you call the file with different url params depending on scenario? something like `jsgenerator.php?origin=script`?

Comment: @kainaw the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can easily be abused and is not always present, this should never be relied upon

Comment: Maybe the [`Accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values)?

Comment: @Martin - The isset is there to prevent PHP from complaining of an undefined variable when `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is not set.

Comment: @castis - I can already achieve the same effect by looking at whether the path ends with .js or .css - I am looking for a way for the server to tell once called, not a way to tell the server as part of the URL.